# Is there a more elegant way of removing seconds from a TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, timespan

Assuming I have a `TimeSpan` that is equal to 07:10:30, I can use the following code to strip the seconds from it:

```
myTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(myTimeSpan.Hours, myTimeSpan.Minutes, 0)
```

Is this appropriate, or is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: I think this is very fine approach.

Comment: Do you also want to strip the [`Days`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.days) component from the `TimeSpan` value? Because that's what your current code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes((long) myTimeSpan.TotalMinutes)
```

This removes any time component smaller than one minute, while keeping anything larger, like days, hours etc. Use [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-5.0) if you want rounding to nearest minute instead of truncating.

Comment: Is this safe from arithmetic overflow (double => int)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Well [it covers you for 4086 years](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E31%29+%2F+%28minutes+in+1+year%29) so I think you'll be safe

Comment: @Charlieface so striping minutes from the grand opening of [Khufu's pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Pyramid_of_Giza) till now is not recommended. 

Comment: @Charlieface A solution should support the extrema of `TimeSpan`'s domain.

Answer (score 1):

Make an extension method that rounds towards zero to the nearest `TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute`.

```
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
    public static TimeSpan WithoutSeconds(this TimeSpan ts)
    {
        const long ps = TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute;
        long roundedTicks = ts.Ticks / ps * ps;
        return new TimeSpan(roundedTicks);
    }
}
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticks?view=net-5.0#System_TimeSpan_Ticks